# Axios POST request to Twillio returns with an Authentication Error?

Tags: node.js, axios, twilio

in Node.js, I am trying to send a POST request with Axios to Twilio and send an SMS message to my phone. But I am getting an 'error: Authentication Error - No credentials provided ? Here is the code:

```
const body = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8',
  Body: 'hi from vsc',
  To: toNumber,
  From: fromNumber,
};

const headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8',
  Authorization: `Basic ${accountSID}:${authToken}`,
};

exports.axios = () => axios.post(`https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/${accountSID}/Messages.json`, body, headers).then((res) => {
  console.log(res, 'res');
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

I also tried to use the same parameters with POSTMAN and the POST request is successful. I also tried to encode my authorization username and password to Base 64, but with no success.
I wrote to Twilio customer help but haven`t received any replies yet.

Comment: not a direct answer, but is there a reason you have chosen not to use twilio's Node sdk for this? https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/node

Comment: Yes previously I have used the sdk, but I have a number of requests that are executed and axios is a better option when Im writing  test and making wrapper functions.

Comment: maybe you need to base64 encode: ${accountSID}:${authToken}

Comment: I did try to base64 encode, same result.

Comment: Authorization: `Basic ${base64.encode(`${process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID}:${process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN}`

Comment: If it makes a difference, [the Twilio library uses axios under the hood](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/blob/292026ff400449952ca057c6c10d41d15d58b7a0/lib/base/RequestClient.js#L4).

Comment: Good spot by @philnash - line 80 may help you out
https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/blob/292026ff400449952ca057c6c10d41d15d58b7a0/lib/base/RequestClient.js#L80

Answer (score 2):

Axios makes an `auth` option available that takes an object with `username` and `password` options. You can use this with the `username` set to your account SID and `password` set to your auth token.

The headers object should be sent as the headers parameter of a config object in the third parameter to `axios.post`. Like so:

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('Body','Hello from vcs');
params.append('To',toNumber);
params.append('From',fromNumber);

const headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8',
};

exports.axios = () => axios.post(
  `https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/${accountSID}/Messages.json`,
  params,
  { 
    headers,
    auth: {
      username: accountSID,
      password: authToken
    }
  }
}).then((res) => {
  console.log(res, 'res');
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Tried it, and got error : message: "A 'To' phone number is required.". Like I said I tried to simulate this in Postman and the msg is sent to my phone successfully. I guess the authorization is ok because I don't get an error message 'Authentication Error - No credentials provided ' ?

Comment: Yeah, auth is now fine, but it’s not sending the body correctly. And that’s because the body needs to be sent as url encoded parameters, not as a JSON object. I’m on the go right now, so can’t update my answer, but look into building the body using `URLSearchParams`.

Comment: Yes!,  that did the trick using URLSearchParams. Thank you 
If somebody has the same issue:
const params = new URLSearchParams();

params.append('Body','Hello from vcs');
params.append('To',toNumber);
params.append('From',fromNumber);

Comment: Thanks for doing that yourself, I'll update my answer to show the full result.

Answer (score 0):

Headers is actually a field of config, try something like this:

```
const config = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8',
    Authorization: `Basic ${accountSID}:${authToken}`,
  }
}

axios.post(URL, data, config).then(...)
```

Comment: Tried this too, and got error : message: "A 'To' phone number is required.". I guess the authorization is ok because I don't get an error message 'Authentication Error - No credentials provided ' now ?

Answer (score 0):

Or this (general example calling a Twilio endpoint)

```
const axios = require('axios');

const roomSID = 'RM1...';
const participantSID = 'PA8...';


const ACCOUNT_SID = process.env.ACCOUNT_SID;
const AUTH_TOKEN = process.env.AUTH_TOKEN;

 const URL = "https://insights.twilio.com/v1/Video/Rooms/"+roomSID+"/Participants/"+participantSID;
    axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: URL,
      auth: {
        username: ACCOUNT_SID,
        password: AUTH_TOKEN
      }
    })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

```
const params = new URLSearchParams();

params.append('Body','Hello from vcs');
params.append('To',toNumber);
params.append('From',fromNumber);

exports.axios = () => axios.post(
  `https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/${accountSID}/Messages.json`,
  params,
  {
    auth: {
      username: accountSID,
      password: authToken,
    },
  },
).then((res) => {
  console.log(res, 'res');
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The previous solutions did not work for me. I encountered either the `Can't find variable: btoa` error or `A 'To' phone number is required.`.

Using `qs` worked for me:

```
import qs from 'qs';
import axios from 'axios';

const TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID = ""
const TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN = ""
const FROM = ""
const TO = ""

const sendText = async (message: string) => {
  try {
    const result = await axios.post(
      `https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/${TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID}/Messages.json`,
      qs.stringify({
        Body: message,
        To: TO,
        From: FROM,
      }),
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        auth: {
          username: TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID,
          password: TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN,
        },
      },
    );
    console.log({result});
  } catch (e) {
    console.log({e});
    console.log({e: e.response?.data});
  }
};
```